# Scalingo deploy error: "Could not detect rake tasks" ( Rails 6.1 )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6.1, gemfile.lock

I have a freshly created rails app that I'm unable to deploy on Scalingo PaaS.

Whenever I try to deploy, I get the following error: `Could not detect rake tasks`

Here is an extract of the backtrace:

```
Fetching source code
-----> Installing bundler 2.1.4
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.7.4
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.1.4
Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4

[...]

-----> Detecting rake tasks

!
!     Could not detect rake tasks
!     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
!     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
!     /build/36bde46d-610a-4ffc-a268-134506db79f1/config/boot.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)
!     from /build/36bde46d-610a-4ffc-a268-134506db79f1/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
!     from /build/36bde46d-610a-4ffc-a268-134506db79f1/bin/rake:3:in `require_relative'
!     from /build/36bde46d-610a-4ffc-a268-134506db79f1/bin/rake:3:in `<main>'
!
/tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
and using the production group of your Gemfile.
/build/36bde46d-610a-4ffc-a268-134506db79f1/config/boot.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)
from /build/36bde46d-610a-4ffc-a268-134506db79f1/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /build/36bde46d-610a-4ffc-a268-134506db79f1/bin/rake:3:in `require_relative'
from /build/36bde46d-610a-4ffc-a268-134506db79f1/bin/rake:3:in `<main>'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:1111:in `rake'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:190:in `log'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:72:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /tmp/tmp.MRJqSkbTtB/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:51:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:1132:in `allow_git'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:110:in `block in compile'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /tmp/tmp.MRJqSkbTtB/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:51:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:95:in `compile'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:62:in `block in compile'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /tmp/tmp.MRJqSkbTtB/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:51:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:60:in `compile'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:42:in `block in compile'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /tmp/tmp.MRJqSkbTtB/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:51:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:41:in `compile'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:35:in `block in compile'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /tmp/tmp.MRJqSkbTtB/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:51:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:34:in `compile'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/rails6.rb:20:in `block in compile'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /tmp/tmp.MRJqSkbTtB/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:51:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/rails6.rb:18:in `compile'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/bin/support/ruby_compile:20:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/base.rb:190:in `log'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/bin/support/ruby_compile:19:in `block in <main>'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /tmp/tmp.MRJqSkbTtB/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
from /tmp/buildpack708571117/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
!     An error occurred during buildpack compilation
 !   Error deploying the application
!   → Invalid return code from buildpack
```

I use the following stack:

- ruby 2.7.4
- rails 6.1.4.3
- bundler 2.1.4

Based on the error message, I tried to run `bundle exec rake -P` on my local machine and it works as expected. Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this issue from happening, add the ruby platform to the lockfile.

Run the following command:

```
bundle lock --add-platform ruby
```

Then commit your `Gemfile.lock`.
The deployment should pass now.